# do array() destroy all previous values?

Tags: php, arrays

I have an $array with some values stored on it. Now, if I do :

```
$array=array();
```

all values/index are deleted? Or I need to use unset() before it?

Comment: it so hard to check out?

Comment: hmm ... SO told me that "yes" was not a valid answer.

Comment: "yes" is too short - you have to be a bit more verbose.

Comment: Like. "Yes: You need to eat an apple a day to stay healthy, wealthy, and wise..." ;-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A **new** array is being created with `array()` and this **new** array object is assigned to the variable `$array`.

The variable (`$array`) no longer points to the *original* array object -- and because PHP is a garbage collected language -- the *original* array object will be eligible for reclamation *if (and only if)* it is no longer strongly reachable from a root object. (The actual time the previous array object and objects it contained are actually deleted depends on other factors.)

Happy coding.

---

See [PHP Garbage Collection Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/features.gc.php) for more details -- PHP uses a hybrid GC (ref-count and cycle-breaking).

Answer (score 2):

Yes the reassignment just wipes out all the data from the array. But to get clear understanding of  the garbage collection please check the [PHP Reference Counting Basics](http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.gc.refcounting-basics.php).

Answer (score 2):

```
$array = array('apples', 'oranges', 'bananas');
print_r($array);
//Array ( [0] => apples [1] => oranges [2] => bananas ) 

$array = array();
print_r($array);
//Array ( )
```

Comment: Right. But this doesn't address if this is a safe operation. (It isn't in C for a manually allocated object, for instance). Just expand on the answer a little bit.

Answer (score 0):

Your intent would be clearer if you used something like

```
$array = null;
```

(and even clearer if you used a better name than $array!)