# Issue deleting session variables

Tags: php, session, unset

I am having a problem deleting/unsetting session variables.

For example if I have 3 items in a shopping cart **1,2,3** and I deleted all those items. They should be deleted from the session but instead they're hidden.

**Unset both variables**
This is where I unset the 2 session variables `cart_array` and `minicart`

```
 <?php
      if (isset($_POST['index_to_remove']) && (!empty($_SESSION["cart_array"]["minicart"]))) {
        // Access the array and run code to remove that array index
        $key_to_remove = $_POST['index_to_remove'];
        if (count($_SESSION["cart_array"]["minicart"]) <= 1) {
            unset($_SESSION["cart_array"]["minicart"]);
        } else {
            unset($_SESSION["cart_array"]["minicart"]["$key_to_remove"]);
            sort($_SESSION["cart_array"]["minicart"]);
        }
    }
?>
```

**HTML**

```
   echo '<form action="cart.php" method="post">
            <input name="deleteBtn' . $item_id . '" 
            type="submit" value="Delete" />
            <input name="index_to_remove" 
            type="hidden" value="' . $i . '" />
            </form>';
```

also in this header.php page I echo out the both session varibles `cart_array` and `minicart`

**MY QUESTION IS/ ISSUES IS**

if you look in **unset variables**  it is meant to unset both session variables `cary_array` and `minicart` based on the itemid which is assigned to those sessions. 
Now if I  click on the delete button this deletes the item from cart BUT *WHY ISN'T IT DELETING the session variable `cary_array` and `minicart` from the session?

I know it has been deleted because the code below shows that instead of the session variable getting deleted(unset) is not

```
if(isset($_SESSION ['cart_array']) && !empty($_SESSION['cart_array'])) {
   echo ("I am still here");
    }
```

Comment: You did not `unset($_SESSION['cart_array'])`, just Arrays within it, so your test would `echo 'I am still here'`.

Comment: Do you have session_start() in this code unsetting the sessions?

Comment: @PHPglue can u explain it more and maybe example please

Comment: @Colandus u dont need start_session for every php tags but i do have it at the top of the page as shown in the question :)

Comment: oh i did not understand your question properly... now i see... and yes he is right. you are only unsetting the arrays value, "minicart"... u must unset($_SESSION['cart_array']) if u want to remove that one... that's what you wanted right? remove the whole 'cart_array' from session?

Comment: `$_SESSION` is a super global Array. In this case you have an Array element called `'cart_array'`, which is an Array itself holding a `'minicart'` Array, which can hold your `$_POST['index_to_remove']`, which you are storing in your `$key_to_remove` variable, that doesn't need to be in double quotes in your multidimensional `$_SESSION` Array, by the way. `$_POST['index_to_remove']` actually comes from an HTML element on your page, based on `name='index_to_remove'`. Well maybe not, if you are using AJAX or another Web Service that sends `$_POST` data.

Comment: @Colandus my question is how will i delete those two  session variables completely from the session. Alsowhere Am i only unsetting "minicart"? I am unsetting both `unset($_SESSION["cart_array"]["minicart"]);`

Comment: yes that is only unsetting the minicart one... if u wanted to unset cart_array you exclude the ["minicart"] part. `unset($_SESSION['cart_array'])`
just as well as if you wrote `$_SESSION["cart_array"]["minicart"] = "hello"` it doesn't make `$_SESSION["cart_array"]` into "hello" right? It's only the ["minicart"] value that is affected

Comment: You are only unsetting the `'minicart'` Array, therefore also properties and values it contians, but not unsetting `'cart_array'`.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
$_SESSION['cart_array'] = Array();//This should empty the cart.
```

Then test only for empty. The reason is most likely due to the way PHP's GC works. Read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5844911/612717) for better explanation.

Comment: will this delete the session? because if not about just deleting the item from the cart i need to delete the session varibles that the items in the cart are assigned to in other for `<?php echo ($_SESSION ['minicart']) ?>` and <?php echo ($_SESSION ['cart_array']) ?> not to show

Comment: in other to stop those 2 variables from showing in the the echo I need to delete the session variables.

Comment: You can run `unset($_SESSION['cart_array'])` after you reset the array.

Comment: that takes care of the `cart_array` what about the `minicart`. I tried `$_SESSION['cart_array']["minicart"] = Array();` but still nothing

Comment: do u think because i have minicart like

`$_SESSION ['minicart'] = $minicartTotal = money_format("%n", $cartTotal);`

Comment: If you use `$_SESSION['minicart']`, then do unset for that too. For a faster result, you can use `$_SESSION['minicart'] = null;`

Comment: @ ChibuezeOpata i did this just after unsetting the `cart_array` but its not removing the `minicart` session variable but the cart_array has been remove

Answer (score 2):

When you do:

```
unset($_SESSION['cart_array']['minicart']);
```

you are just unsetting "minicart", not "cart_array".

If you want to unset both "cart_array" and "minicart", you should just do:

```
unset($_SESSION['cart_array']);
```

or

```
$_SESSION['cart_array'] = array();
```

To test if the arrays are empty or not, just:

```
if ($_SESSION['cart_array']):
else:
endif;
```

Comment: no not `$_SESSION['cart_array'] = array();` then it's doing same as now (due to the fact "minicart" is the sole value in "cart_array", otherwise it would not be completely the same effect although it is not the right solution)... edited it for u

Comment: ifi take out "minicart" i get an underfined index for both minicart and cart_array whichi echo out in `<li class="item_amount"><a>
     Item
     <span id="items"><?php echo count($_SESSION["cart_array"])?></span>
     </a></li>
     <li class="cart_total">
     Total
     <span id="cart_total"><?php echo ($_SESSION ['minicart']) ?></span></a></li> `

Comment: Perhaps you should not unset the cart_array session then? Just leave it as it is? Why do you want to clean it anyway? Yes of course you will get undefined index if you have removed the array from sessions.

Comment: @Colandus if u do online shopping and for example u go into topman website add an item into cart on top of the page it tells u how many items u have in your cart `cart_array` and then the total price for all your item `minicart`.

Comment: and when u delete an item from cart it deleted the total price change on the little cart, etc and if it empty u will get 0 for item and 0.00  for price. That is what it is... atm the item shows along with the price but when the cart is complete empty nothing should show

Comment: @Amy, yes and then why would you want to completely unset the cart_array? If you wish to use `count($_SESSION['cart_array'])` you may not unset it. But if you do really wish to unset it, it is to use `unset($_SESSION['cart_array']);`

Comment: @Colandus if u see I am only unset the session variables assign by the id getting posted from the form so this only affects the item getting deleted not all the items

Comment: If you unset "cart_array" and then you echo its value, it will always return an undefined index error, this is because you have your PHP error_reporting set as E_ALL. To fix this, either you test your array before echoing it, like <?php echo isset($_SESSION['cart_array']) ?count($_SESSION['cart_array']) : ''; ?>, or you change E_ALL to E_ALL & ~ E_NOTICE in your php.ini configuration, which by the way, should be set like this for production environments.

Comment: @Danny Herran I added `$_SESSION['minicart'] = null;` and this works `BUT` it only counts all the `cart_array` as `1` even though I have more than `1` item in the cart. also if I delete 1 item from the cart it delete every item. Any idea why?

Comment: @DannyHerran `cart_array` where I am storing arrays like `Array ( [0] => Array ( [item_id] => 2 [size] => 12 Inch [type] => grey [quantity] => 1 ) )` and `minicart` is where I am storing the overall total from the cart in other to echo it into into another page. because `minicart` is not an array... how can i store this session variables please

Comment: @Amy: You need to implement a proper model for your cart. You can open a new question and ask this. The overall total should be a property and not a field that is calculated automatically based on the cart array. Instead of a `minicart` variable, have a method that counts `cart_array`

Comment: @ChibuezeOpata  this is how the overall total is calculated `$pricetotal = $price * $each_item['quantity'];
$cartTotal = $pricetotal + $cartTotal;` `$cartTotal = money_format("%n", $cartTotal);
 $cartTotal = "<div style='font-size:18px; margin-top:12px;' align='right'>Cart Total : ".$cartTotal." GBR</div>";
   `

Comment: @ChibuezeOpata that total is when shouldnt in the cart page and so it should be stored in `minicart` session so i can be able to echo it out into different pages so they use can always know their total without having to go to cart page to find out

Comment: @Amy: Please remember that this is a QA site. When you ask questions, follow up answers based on your question. If you ask how to ensure that variables are properly unset, you should know when your question has been answered. `$minicart` can always be calculated the same way you calculate `$pricetotal`. In your new question I told you how you could sum all item prices and provide `$total` to user any time so they don't have to go to cart page.

Comment: @ChibuezeOpata r u referring to the answer u posted?